# How to make sure Doctrine doesn't cache null values?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use `symfony2` with `doctrine`. Is there a way to not cache null results on query?

```
$query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'example');
```

Comment: No, you have to expire the cache on your own when the result is `null` - a null result is still a result for the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the result cache driver with your own class and wrap its "save" method.

There are multiple cache provider and they all extend [this](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php) abstract class

Once you have created the wrapper you can directly define your cache provider class in your config.yml (or else if you moved the doctrine's parameters). [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) is the configuration reference for Doctrine.
In the page linked above you should look at the parameter `class` under `result_cache_driver`.